# How to figure class of a running thread

Tags: java, multithreading

My program seems to have an issue with threads not finishing, and I'm trying to find out why.

I use several different thread classes, and have no idea which one (or maybe all) is not finishing. I tried to fetch running threads and cast them to find out their class, but it's not working.

One of the thread classes:

```
 public class Thread_Searcher extends Thread {

    private HttpURLConnection connection;
    int RelationValue = 0;

    Thread_Searcher getThread_Searcher() {
    return this;
    }

    public void TimePast() {
    if (connection != null) {
        connection.disconnect();
    }
    }
}
```

Trying to figure which class they belong to:

```
Set<Thread> threadSet = ScannerThread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
Thread[] threadArray = threadSet.toArray(new Thread[threadSet.size()]);
for (int x = 0; x < threadArray.length; x++) {
try {
    System.out.println(this.toString() + " SearchURL " + x);
    System.out.println(this.toString() + " " + threadArray[x].isAlive() + " " + threadArray[x].toString());
    try {
    Thread_Searcher test = (Thread_Searcher) threadArray[x];
    System.out.println(this.toString() + " SearchURL " + x + "Thread_Searcher");
    } catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println(this.toString() + " SearchURL Thread_Searcher " + e.getMessage());
    //CastErrors(e);
    }
    try {
    Thread_LinkScanner test = (Thread_LinkScanner) threadArray[x];
    System.out.println(this.toString() + " SearchURL " + x + "Thread_LinkScanner");
    System.out.println(this.toString() + " " + x + " " + test.Status);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println(this.toString() + " SearchURL Thread_LinkScanner " + e.getMessage());
    //CastErrors(e);
    }
    try {
    Thread_PhraseSearcher test = (Thread_PhraseSearcher) threadArray[x];
    System.out.println(this.toString() + " SearchURL " + x + "Thread_PhraseSearcher");
    } catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println(this.toString() + " SearchURL Thread_PhraseSearcher " + e.getMessage());
    //CastErrors(e);
    }
    try {
    Thread_URLFinder test = (Thread_URLFinder) threadArray[x];
    System.out.println(this.toString() + " SearchURL " + x + "Thread_URLFinder");
    } catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println(this.toString() + " SearchURL Thread_URLFinder " + e.getMessage());
    //CastErrors(e);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    CastErrors(e);
}
}
```

The above code gives me the below output:

```
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL 0
Control.Controller@91161c7 true Thread[Attach Listener,5,system]
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL 1
Control.Controller@91161c7 true Thread[Thread-23,5,main]
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL 2
Control.Controller@91161c7 true Thread[Thread-4,5,main]
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL 3
Control.Controller@91161c7 true Thread[Finalizer,8,system]
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL 4
Control.Controller@91161c7 true Thread[Thread-19,5,main]
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL 5
Control.Controller@91161c7 true Thread[TimerQueue,5,system]
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL 6
Control.Controller@91161c7 true Thread[Thread-8,5,main]
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL 7
Control.Controller@91161c7 true Thread[Thread-17,5,main]
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL 8
Control.Controller@91161c7 true Thread[DestroyJavaVM,5,main]
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL 9
Control.Controller@91161c7 true Thread[Keep-Alive-Timer,8,system]
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_PhraseSearcher java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_PhraseSearcher
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_URLFinder java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_URLFinder
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_Searcher java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_Searcher
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_LinkScanner java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_LinkScanner
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_PhraseSearcher java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_PhraseSearcher
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_URLFinder java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_URLFinder
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_Searcher java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_Searcher
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_LinkScanner java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_LinkScanner
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_PhraseSearcher java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_PhraseSearcher
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_URLFinder java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_URLFinder
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_Searcher java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_Searcher
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_LinkScanner java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_LinkScanner
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_PhraseSearcher java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_PhraseSearcher
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_URLFinder java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_URLFinder
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_Searcher java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_Searcher
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_LinkScanner java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_LinkScanner
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_PhraseSearcher java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_PhraseSearcher
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_URLFinder java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_URLFinder
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_Searcher java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_Searcher
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_LinkScanner java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_LinkScanner
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_PhraseSearcher java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_PhraseSearcher
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_URLFinder java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_URLFinder
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_Searcher java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_Searcher
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_LinkScanner java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_LinkScanner
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_PhraseSearcher java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_PhraseSearcher
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_URLFinder java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_URLFinder
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_Searcher java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_Searcher
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_LinkScanner java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_LinkScanner
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_PhraseSearcher java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_PhraseSearcher
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_URLFinder java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_URLFinder
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_Searcher java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_Searcher
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_LinkScanner java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_LinkScanner
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_PhraseSearcher java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_PhraseSearcher
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_URLFinder java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_URLFinder
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_Searcher java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_Searcher
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_LinkScanner java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_LinkScanner
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_PhraseSearcher java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_PhraseSearcher
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_URLFinder java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_URLFinder
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL 10
Control.Controller@91161c7 true Thread[Signal Dispatcher,9,system]
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_Searcher java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_Searcher
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_LinkScanner java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_LinkScanner
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_PhraseSearcher java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_PhraseSearcher
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_URLFinder java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_URLFinder
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL 11
Control.Controller@91161c7 true Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main]
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_Searcher java.awt.EventDispatchThread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_Searcher
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_LinkScanner java.awt.EventDispatchThread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_LinkScanner
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_PhraseSearcher java.awt.EventDispatchThread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_PhraseSearcher
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_URLFinder java.awt.EventDispatchThread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_URLFinder
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL 12
Control.Controller@91161c7 true Thread[AWT-Windows,6,system]
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_Searcher java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_Searcher
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_LinkScanner java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_LinkScanner
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_PhraseSearcher java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_PhraseSearcher
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_URLFinder java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_URLFinder
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL 13
Control.Controller@91161c7 true Thread[Thread-12,5,main]
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_Searcher java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_Searcher
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_LinkScanner java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_LinkScanner
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_PhraseSearcher java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_PhraseSearcher
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_URLFinder java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_URLFinder
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL 14
Control.Controller@91161c7 true Thread[Thread-6,5,main]
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_Searcher java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_Searcher
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_LinkScanner java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_LinkScanner
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_PhraseSearcher java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_PhraseSearcher
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_URLFinder java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_URLFinder
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL 15
Control.Controller@91161c7 true Thread[AWT-Shutdown,5,system]
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_Searcher java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_Searcher
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_LinkScanner java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_LinkScanner
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_PhraseSearcher java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_PhraseSearcher
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_URLFinder java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_URLFinder
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL 16
Control.Controller@91161c7 true Thread[Java2D Disposer,10,system]
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_Searcher java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_Searcher
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_LinkScanner java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_LinkScanner
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_PhraseSearcher java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_PhraseSearcher
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_URLFinder java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_URLFinder
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL 17
Control.Controller@91161c7 true Thread[Thread-10,5,main]
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_Searcher java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_Searcher
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_LinkScanner java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_LinkScanner
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_PhraseSearcher java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_PhraseSearcher
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_URLFinder java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_URLFinder
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL 18
Control.Controller@91161c7 true Thread[Thread-2,5,main]
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_Searcher java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_Searcher
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_LinkScanner java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_LinkScanner
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_PhraseSearcher java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_PhraseSearcher
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_URLFinder java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_URLFinder
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL 19
Control.Controller@91161c7 true Thread[Thread-21,5,main]
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_Searcher java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_Searcher
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_LinkScanner java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_LinkScanner
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_PhraseSearcher java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_PhraseSearcher
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_URLFinder java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_URLFinder
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL 20
Control.Controller@91161c7 true Thread[Thread-14,5,main]
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_Searcher java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_Searcher
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_LinkScanner java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_LinkScanner
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_PhraseSearcher java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_PhraseSearcher
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_URLFinder java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_URLFinder
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL 21
Control.Controller@91161c7 true Thread[Reference Handler,10,system]
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_Searcher java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_Searcher
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_LinkScanner java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_LinkScanner
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_PhraseSearcher java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_PhraseSearcher
Control.Controller@91161c7 SearchURL Thread_URLFinder java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler cannot be cast to Threads.Thread_URLFinder
```

So, how can I find out the class of the running threads?

Comment: What do you mean by that? Threads don't have classes. Threads execute code, which can be in any class(es).

Comment: In theory, your method *should* work, though it is not well-written. But for some reason most of the threads are of class `Thread` rather than your own classes, suggesting that perhaps you are not starting them properly. Can you add the code that start the threads to your question?

Comment: Directly: `threadArray[i].getClass()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the `values` from your `getAllStackTraces` result, not `keys`. You can scan through the stack frames of each thread, and print out what place in the code is currently being executed by that thread. 
Something like this, maybe:

```
for(Map.Entry<Thread,StackTraceElement[]> entry: ScannerThread.getAllStackTraces().entries()) {
    System.out.println("\n***\n" + entry.getKey().getName())
    for(StackTraceElement e: entry.getKey().getValue()) 
        System.out.println("\t" + e);
}
```

Also note, that, if you have access to the system where your program is running, you can send it a -3 (SIGQUIT) signal (if it is in terminal, hit `Ctl-\`), to make it dump similar (but better) output to its stderr.

Answer (score 0):

When you get all the stack traces with `Thread.getAllStackTraces()`, you get the stack traces of each of the threads.
This means you have the stack including the `getClassName` and even the line number within that class.  From this you should be able to determine what you want to know.

I suggest you log the stack traces of threads which are taking too long, however if you are waiting for the HTTP request you may find it is taking too long to get the reply. e.g. the server is taking too long or it takes a long to time upload or download.